# Should I use platicizer as an additive to mortar

Tags: cement

I keep having problems with the joints in my patio flags, after each winter the joints often break up and it is a major job to keep the patio in good condition. I usually use a mix or Portland cement and Sharp sand in 4:1 ratio but it is clearly not doing the job correctly, Ideally I want strong mortar joints that are hard and preferably able to withstand jet spraying when the patio is cleaned. Should I be using an additive such as a platicizer to strengthen the mortar mix? If so any particular brand?

Comment: The problem is not the mortar - the problem is an unstable base - if what's under the patio moves, **any** mortar will crack.

Comment: I've never heard of cementing patio stone gaps in a freeze zone.  Joints are always filled with lose sand or even gravel.  Is there any reason to believe you can do this?